# is this possible to switch remote branch from local git

Tags: git, centos

my problem is, i have 4 servers and 1 development machine from where i want push all my local changes in git to all 4 server in one command ....you can call it like syncing git repo.

i have tried lots of thing. like making sh file and add 4 times git push command but again i found another complexity about how to send password with push command.

similarly, after pushing all changes by typing 4 times password on sh file..finally i am able to push all changes to the remote but not able to switch that branch on remote side..??

please help me how can i do that

arun

Answer (score 1):

Git does not have support for remote operations, other than "push". An alternative would be to use `ssh` (to access git repos and to do maintenance operations) and export your public key to all four servers.

[Edit]

If you can not use ssh then you can try a less secure aproach

```
git push --repo https://name:password@my-server/repo.git
```

or update the remote url

```
git remote set-url origin https://name:password@my-server/repo.git
```

Comment: ok, but is there any way to send password with push command ...i mean inline password in push command.

Comment: @siversansar, I have updated my answer, I hope it will be of any help